# SQL using postgresql and C3

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a question regarding multiple tables in postgresql and using sql statements in C#. I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE "Board"
(
  board_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  board_serial_number integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Board_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (board_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "Board"
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TABLE "Defect"
(
  defect_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  defect_type text,
  ref_des text,
  board_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT "Defect_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (defect_id),
  CONSTRAINT "Defect_board_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (board_id)
      REFERENCES "Board" (board_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I have a data entry form that always the user to enter a serial number and enter defect type and ref_Des (stand for reference description or part location on a circuit board)

The user can enter a defect and click a button to add the defect to the defect table, the use can do this multiple times to add other defects.

How can I tie the serial number to all the defects added when the user clicks save? I am new to database programming and I just cant seem to figure it out or if I am making more difficult that it is. Please help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "tie the serial number to all the defects added."  Specifically the word "tie"

Comment: I want to insert all defects in the defects table to the given serial number which will be stored in the board table. So if serial number 9999 has x amount of defects, I want to pull that serial number later and see all the related defects for that number. one product can have many defects.

Comment: So it sounds like the user enters the defects and the board_serial_number.  But when you insert data into the defects table, you need to know the defects and the board_id.  So you will need to first execute a SELECT statement to get the board_id from the board_serial_number they entered.  Then, you can insert the defects using that board_id.  Later, when you want to get the defects for a given board_serial_number, you will execute a select statement that JOINs the Board table to the Defects table on board_id.  That will give you the defects, the board_id, and the board_serial_number.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, I dont know if this the most efficient to do this but here is my code. What do you think. I welcome constructive criticism :)

```
 private void addDefect()
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = Connection.getConnection();
            conn.Open();

            DefectType = cboDefectType.Text;
            ResDes = txtRefDes.Text;

            NpgsqlCommand cmd2 = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from \"Board\" where \"board_serial_number\" = :SerialNumber;", conn);
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("SerialNumber", SerialNumber));

            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                DefectBoardID = dr.GetInt64(0);
                cmd2.Dispose();
                dr.Dispose();
                conn.Close();

            }

            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into \"Defect\"(\"defect_type\",\"ref_des\",\"board_id\")" +
                "Values(:DefectType,:RefDes,:BoardID);", conn);


            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("DefectType", DefectType));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("RefDes", ResDes));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("BoardID", DefectBoardID));


            int recordInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (recordInserted == 1)
            {
                lblError.Text = "Defects Added to Board" + SerialNumber + "!";
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Defects were not added to Board" + SerialNumber + "!";
            }
            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```